# sql grab duplicate record with same second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query in sql server:

table:

```
 SELECT [Id]
         ,[BrokerId]
         ,[UserId]
      FROM [UserBroker]
```

values I want to grab:

```
Id  BrokerId    UserId
21288   252055  223177
21291   252055  223178
```

attempt at query:

I want to grab all records that have duplicate userids to one brokerid.  I tried this query but it is incorrect:

```
 SELECT 
  [BrokerId]
  ,[UserId]
 FROM [UserBroker]
 group by [BrokerId],[UserId]
 having count([BrokerId]) = 1 and count([UserId]) > 1
```

Comment: Can you provide more sample data? It almost looks like you're implying that each BrokerId should occur only once (implying that each Broker is related to only one User). Or is it the other way around - that each User should be associated with only one Broker?

Comment: I want to find all data that has multiple userids pointed to 1 brokerid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select UB.ID, UB.BrokerID, UB.userId
FROM userBroker ub
INNER JOIN userBroker mUB
 on Ub.BrokerID = mub.BrokerID
 and Ub.userID <> mub.UserID
GROUP BY UB.ID, UB.BrokerID, UB.userId
ORDER BY UB.BrokerID, UB.userId, UB.Id
```

Returns ID, broker and userIDs where different userID's exist for the same broker.  Note the group by is used incase there were duplicates in the data (the same brokerID and userId exists for different IDs)

Order by used to make the duplicates easier to find; they should be right after eachother.

Answer (score 0):

This returns all those BrokerId's that are related to more than one different UserId:

```
SELECT 
 [BrokerId]
FROM [UserBroker]
group by [BrokerId]
having count(*) > 1
   and count(distinct [UserId]) > 1
```

Without any more information about your data or structure, the `count(distinct [UserId]) > 1` might be excessive (is it really possible to have a BrokerId associated to the same UserId more than once?).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT *,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [BrokerId], [UserId]) c
  FROM [UserBroker]
)
SELECT [Id], [BrokerId], [UserId]
FROM t
WHERE c > 1
```